# Customizing BackColor in XtraGrid DevExpress at VB.net

Tags: vb.net, devexpress, xtragrid, datagridcolumn

is it possible to customizing Back Color of specific column in XtraGrid? I wan't to code it because I will using it in a if condition. I coded but it wont work, I checked it the DevExpress Website, I follow the instructions I put imports and so on then how to code it but still wont work.

This is my code:

```
GridView1.Columns("Name").AppearanceCell.BackColor = Color.Red
```

I appreciated if someone's can solve this :))))

Sincerely...

Answer (score 0):

If you'd like to programmatically change the color of a column based on a condition, you can handle the [GridView.RowCellStyle event](https://docs.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Grid.GridView.RowCellStyle).

See: https://docs.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/115548/controls-and-libraries/data-grid/appearance-and-conditional-formatting#override-custom-appearances-for-selected-cells